# SQL Server JDBC driver 4.0 to support both JDK 1.5 and JDK 1.6

Tags: java, jdbc

The [Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) offers sqljdbc.jar and sqljdbc4.jar. As per the release notes sqljdbc.jar can be used with Java 5 and sqlserver4.jar can be used with Java 6 and 7.

My current project compiles with Java5 so that our customers can run them in Java5 or Java6 or Java7 based on their web/application server support. Current I create one war file for all web/app server. Since Microsoft offers different jars for various JDK are there any way to load appropriate sqljdbc jar based on the Java version with single deployment package?

I could create separate war file for Java5 and Java6 which could solve the problem but want to check with other to see are there any other option.

Comment: I w ould suggest using the JTDS driver. It works a lot better then the microsoft drivers. http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried to find in the release notes that the two different jars serve different JDKs. I could not find that statement. Can you guide me?

Comment: Your link says: *This release of the JDBC Driver is JDBC 4.0 compliant and runs on the Java Development Kit (JDK) version 5.0 or 6.0.*

Comment: Sorry, its not explicitly mentioned but you can find them here. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/8c1721c1-781f-4ad0-b656-a2494f3c3978

Comment: @Venkat OK, I see. Do you use Maven (or gradle)? Then you can build separate war files with the different dependencies.

Comment: @Venkat OT, if you look on the right side of the comment box there is a help link with some useful information. For example if you want to address someone specific in the comments list then you can add an `@` sign in front of the name. Then that person will get a notification. That helps a lot in the interaction.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JDBC 4 adds additional interfaces, `SQLException` subclasses etc. So you most certainly can't use `sqljdbc4.jar` with Java 5, the other way around might be possible, but (and this is a strong but), if the application, or the application server tries to access one of the methods defined in JDBC 4, then it will fail and fail hard.

In other words: either create Java version specific WARs, or deploy the driver separately, and not as part of your application.